# Install nullfs on Debian

Tags: makefile, fuse, cc

I am using a java program. It automatically creates log files in a directory, but I am doing that myself a different way with `tee`. I cannot find an easy way to disable the logs, so I am resorting to using nullfs.

I cloned it with

```
git clone https://github.com/xrgtn/nullfs.git
```

and I ran

```
make nul1fs
```

as instructed. It terminates within a second, with the following output:

```
cc   "-lfuse"  nul1fs.c   -o nul1fs
nul1fs.c:13:18: fatal error: fuse.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [nul1fs] Error 1
```

I tried `apt-get source fuse` and copying fuse.h into the nullfs directory, but nothing changed.
I have FUSE installed. I'm running Debian wheezy x86_64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the development package of FUSE, which contains the `fuse.h` you're missing. Do a `apt-get install libfuse-dev` and it should work.

Copying the header file in the source directory did not work, because in `nul1fs.c` you'll notice that fuse.h is included with angle brackets. This means, the header file will be searched in the system-wide include paths. That usually means `/usr/include`.

---

Note that you then may run into this error:

```
$ make nul1fs
cc   "-lfuse"  nul1fs.c   -o nul1fs
/tmp/ccbt0X7c.o: In function `main':
nul1fs.c:(.text+0x3c3): undefined reference to `fuse_main_real'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [nul1fs] Error 1
```

It's a [documented bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fuse/+bug/878612) with a workaround: put the linker flags after the file lists. I.e. compile nul1fs with:

```
cc nul1fs.c -o nul1fs -lfuse
```

and not with `make nul1fs`, which boils down to

```
cc -lfuse nul1fs.c -o nul1fs
```